# Having a hard time doing this Palindrome on Java

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time learning java and I was hoping to get some type of help on doing this. I'm trying to get the user to input a word and have the system check to see if its a palindrome. I've taken some code from others to get some help but I'm getting stuck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PalidromeTester
{

    public static boolean isPalindrome (String[] word) {
       for (int i=0; i< word.length; i++) { 
            if (!word[i].equals( word[word.length-1-i])){
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 

    // read word
    public static String readWord(Scanner input){
      String word = input.nextLine();
      word = word.toLowerCase();
      return word;
    }

    // display results to the screen
    public static void displayResults(boolean result){
      // display the results
      String msg = "\nThat string ";
      msg += (result == true) ? " IS " : " is NOT ";
      msg += " a palindrome.\n";
      System.out.println(msg);
    }

    // main function
    public static void main(String[] args){
      // input scanner
      System.out.print('\u000C');
      System.out.println("Enter the word: ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      PalidromeTester.readWord(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: How, why, where are you getting stuck? Your current problem description is too vague.

Comment: i cant enter the word when i run the main

Comment: Your isPalindrome method is overcomplicated, just use StringBuilder to check for Palindromes. `public static boolean isPalindrome (String word) {
         if(word.equals(new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString()))
             return true;
         return false;
    }`

Comment: You are never calling your `readWord` method. If you don't call it it won't be executed. Hint: The `public static void main` is the entry method that gets executed when you run the program. Look at what that method does (not much)

Comment: @Aominè, string builder version has double the space requirement and double run time. Certain assignments are very strict about these things.

Comment: @Aominè he doesnt call anything from his main method nevermind the readWord() method.

Comment: doesnt the scanner input get sent into the read word method

Comment: @Vick0123: I don't know what you mean by that. But again:  Its your job as a programmer to write code that calls the methods. If you don't write code that calls the readWord method it might as well not exist.

Comment: PalidromeTester.readWord(input);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your need, I think this is what you need. I have commented the changes done in the code itself to point out to you why the changes were done in the first place. Also remember there are multiple ways to approach a problem, this is merely just one of those possibilities. Feel free to innovate and add your own technique for solving this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome { //<-- added public to the class otherwise main method won't be called

public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) { //<--changed the String[] to String
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (!(word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(word.length() - 1 - i))) { //Since [] will not work on Strings, using charAt() to do the same thing
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// read word
public static String readWord(Scanner input) {
    String word = input.nextLine();
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    return word;
}

// display results to the screen
public static void displayResults(boolean result) {
    // display the results
    String msg = "\nThat string ";
    msg += (result == true) ? " IS " : " is NOT ";
    msg += " a palindrome.\n";
    System.out.println(msg);
}

// main function
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input scanner
    System.out.print('\u000C');
    System.out.println("Enter the word: ");
    String s = readWord(new Scanner(System.in)); //Added a call to the readWord method and also passed a Scanner reference to the method and 
                                                 //storing the read word in String s
    boolean result = isPalindrome(s); //Added a call to the palindrome method and also passing the read string s to the method to find whether
                                      //it is palindrome or not and storing the method return value in boolean result variable
    displayResults(result); //Finally calling the displayResults with the result we got from isPalindrome() to display the appropriate message
}
}
```